# Spring create aspect for all methods with an annotation included in a meta annotation

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, aop, aspectj, spring-annotations

I have an Annotation like this (in Spring Boot 2):

```
package com.test;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface MyAnnotation { }
```

And a meta annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MyAnnotation 
public @interface MyEndpoint{ }
```

How can I define an Aspect in order to be executed before each method that has @MyAnnotation?

If I define it has below,

```
@Before("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(myAnnotation)")
public void authorize(JoinPoint pjp, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) { }
```

then the method `authorize` is called only

```
@MyAnnotation()
public myMethod(){}
```

and NOT in this case:

```
@MyEndpoint()
public myMethod() {}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`@Inherited` annotations only works from annotated classes to subclasses and not in any other case. I explained this in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42607016/1082681) and also show what an AspectJ workaround can look like. You can adapt it to your case. **But** you really need to use AspectJ in order to achieve this, not just Spring AOP.